# Import KML file data inside FormFunction (Interpreter problem?)

Tags: import, cloud-deploy, form-building

I have a KML file with a bunch of (lat,lon) pairs. I can retrieve the pairs by importing the KML file as "Data" and drilling down into it:

```
Import["mykml.kml","Data"][[1,2,2,1,1]]
```

[image]

This yields a `GeoPosition` object with the (lat,lon) points. Passing this to `GeoDistance` calculates the length of the path, which is what I'm after.

Now I want to `CloudDeploy` a `FormFunction` so other folks can run `GeoDistance` on their own KML files; something like

```
form = FormFunction["yourfile" -> "KML", GeoDistance[#yourfile] &]
CloudDeploy[form, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

The problem is that the `FormFunction` imports the KML file without the extra `"Data"` specifier, so that `#yourfile` is some map object instead of a data structure I can drill down into.

How can I tell `FormFunction` to import the `"Data"` in the KML file, and not perform the default importing action?

Comment: Does my answer fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import plain text and then `ImportString`:

```
form = FormFunction[
    "yourfile" -> "Text"
  , GeoDistance[ImportString[#yourfile, {"KML", "Data"}][[1, 2, 2, 1, 1]]] &
];

CloudDeploy[form, Permissions -> "Public"]
```