# How do you upload text from a PDF using FormFunction?

Tags: import, pdf-format, wolfram-cloud, form-building

I can import text from a PDF using

```
text = Import[filename, "Plaintext"];
```

I'd like to do the same thing using FormFunction, but am unsure how. I've tried the following:

```
FormFunction[
 "file" -> "PDF",
 #file &,
 "Text"
 ]
```

which seems to import an image of the PDF. I've also tried

```
FormFunction["file" -> "Text", 
 #file &,
 "Text"
 ]
```

which doesn't allow PDFs to be entered. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does my answer fit your needs?>

Comment: Yes, apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import a specific element of a pdf you can use `"Text"` type and proceed with `ImportString` and elements spec:

```
FormFunction[
  "file" -> "Text"
, ImportString[#file, {"PDF", "Plaintext"}] &
]
```

It does not mean you will always get what you expect. It depends what the pdf really contains. Text inside can be e.g. rasterized.

Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148358/5478